# Centralized & versioned file based system for a web application deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, s3fs

I am trying to create an Centralized file based repository where I can upload all the configuration files needed for an application to run which is deployed as a pod inside the Kubernetes. Any suggestion on achieving this functionality ? Can the file based repository version the files uploaded ?

I see that s3fs-fuse can be used to achieve this, but i lack to see that, it wont support versioning the added config files in the S3 bucket.
https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Any other suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [elastic file system](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/whatisefs.html) which is [supported](http://Amazon%20EKS%20Announces%20Support%20for%20the%20Amazon%20EFS%20CSI%20Driver) by EKS:

> Applications running in Kubernetes can use EFS file systems to **share data between pods** in a scale-out group, or with other applications running within or outside of Kubernetes. EFS can also help Kubernetes applications be highly available because all data written to EFS is written to multiple AWS Availability zones. If a Kubernetes pod is terminated and relaunched, the **CSI driver will reconnect the EFS file system**, even if the pod is relaunched in a different AWS Availability Zone.

But its not S3 and it **does not have versioning** of files such as S3 has. You would have to add such functionality yourself, e.g. by keeping everything in a git repository on the EFS file system.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you think in EFS we can manually upload the files and it is possible to edit the files ?

Comment: @babs84 Yes. EFS is managed NFS file system. So it behaves exactly as regular NFS. Its not object storage, like S3.

Comment: Thank you. One final question on achieving the Versioning. You mentioned that we can achieve the versioning by keeping everything in a git repository on the EFS file system ? what do you mean by that ? In the Amazon EFS UI, there is no option to upload the files as well

Comment: @babs84 This is something you have to do yourself, like you would do on a local workstation. EFS does not have any build-in mechanism for versioning.

Comment: @babs84 No problem. Glad could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use git?

The following article contains an example which runs a `git clone` within an initContainer:

https://blog.frankel.ch/versatility-kubernetes-initcontainer/